# Upgrade OpenVPN on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn, upgrade

I have an OpenVPN access server running in my AWS Ubuntu environment, version 2.0.12-Ubuntu14.  I need to upgrade this to at least version 2.1.  What's the best way of doing this?

I tried apt-get, but that tells me that I already have the most recent version.

```
me@myserver:~$ apt-get upgrade openvpn-as -s
NOTE: This is only a simulation!
    apt-get needs root privileges for real execution.
    Keep also in mind that locking is deactivated,
    so don't depend on the relevance to the real current situation!
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
openvpn-as is already the newest version.
```

(I don't want to install a new server instance from an AMI, since I'd have to recreate a lot of users.)

EDIT - Solution posted below.

Comment: https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/OpenvpnSoftwareRepos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what worked: https://openvpn.net/index.php/access-server/section-faq-openvpn-as/69-virtual-appliance/174-how-to-upgrade-the-virtual-appliance-to-a-new-version-of-the-access-server.html

```
sudo -s
wget http://swupdate.openvpn.org/as/openvpn-as-2.1.2-Ubuntu14.amd_64.deb
dpkg -i openvpn-as-2.1.2-Ubuntu14.amd_64.deb
```